# Как остановить сервис Foreground после перезапуска приложения android

Tags: android, kotlin, service

В приложении создаю сервис, который в фоне обновляет местоположение. При полном закрытии и открытии приложения не могу разбиндить уведомление и его удалить. Для удобства написал мененджер сервиса.

```
var locationUpdateService: LocationUpdateService? = null
var isBound = false
val serviceClass = LocationUpdateService::class.java
val serviceIntent = Intent(appContext, serviceClass)

private val myConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
        val binder = iBinder as LocationUpdateService.LocationUpdateServiceBinder
        locationUpdateService = binder.getService()
        isBound = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {
        isBound = false
    }
}

fun startLocationUpdateForeground() {
    if (!isServiceRunning(serviceClass.javaClass)) {
        appContext.startService(serviceIntent)
        appContext.bindService(serviceIntent, myConnection, AppCompatActivity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    } else {
        Logger.logE("Service already running.")
        MakeToast.makeInfo("Service already running.")
        appContext.bindService(serviceIntent, myConnection, AppCompatActivity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
}

fun stopLocationUpdateForeground() {
    try {
        appContext.unbindService(myConnection)
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Logger.logE("Error Unbinding Service.")
    }
    if (isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
        appContext.stopService(serviceIntent)
    } else {
        Logger.logE("Service not running.")
        MakeToast.makeInfo("Service not running.")
    }
}

private fun isServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
    val activityManager =
        appContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

    // Loop through the running services
    for (service in activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Сам сервис:

```
class LocationUpdateService : Service() {
companion object {
    const val CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID "
    const val CHANNEL_NAME = "CHANNEL_NAME "
}

private val myBinder = LocationUpdateServiceBinder()

private lateinit var mNotification: Notification
private val mNotificationId: Int = 999

private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? =
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext)

val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        for (location in locationResult.locations) {
            val loc = Location(
                location.latitude,
                location.longitude
            )
            MakeToast.makeError(loc.toString())
            updateMyLocation(loc)
        }
    }
}

private fun settingsLocationRequests(): LocationRequest? {
    val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    locationRequest.interval = 120000
    locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10F;
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
    return locationRequest
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
    return myBinder
}

inner class LocationUpdateServiceBinder : Binder() {
    fun getService(): LocationUpdateService {
        return this@LocationUpdateService
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Logger.logI("Service started.")
    getNotification(applicationContext)
    startLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    return Service.START_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Logger.logI("Service destroyed.")
    stopLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    stopForeground(true)
}


override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    stopSelf()
}

fun startLocationUpdates(locationCallback: LocationCallback?) {
    if (!checkSelfPermission()) {
        return
    }
    settingsLocationRequests()?.let {
        fusedLocationProviderClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            it,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    }
}

fun stopLocationUpdates(locationCallback: LocationCallback?) {
    fusedLocationProviderClient!!.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
}

private fun updateMyLocation(location: Location) {
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: вы закрыли приложение, но сервис то по прежнему работает, он же Foreground. поэтому и не убирается уведомление.

Comment: Да, возможно неправильно мысли свои изложил. Сервис и должен работать в фоне. Приложение я полностью. Закрываю. Заново открываю и теперь я хочу завершить фоновую работу. Как мне это можно реализовать? Стоп сервис в таком случае пишет что сервис не запущен. Видимо после переоткрытая приложения — заново создаются все классы и старое уведомление потеряло связь с новым открытым приложением. Возможно мне разбиндить и обратиться к CHANNEL_ID, и как-то вызвать метод, который закроет уведомление и завершит фоновый сервис?

Comment: покажите код, как вы запускаете сервис. и как пытаетесь его остановить через stopService

Comment: запускаю с activiti, где инициализируется мененджер и при нажатии на кнопку вызываю метод: locationManager.stopLocationUpdateForeground()

Comment: appContext.stopService(serviceIntent) попробуйте добавить это в метод stopLocationUpdateForeground

Comment: Убрал условие, чтобы всегда срабатывал метод appContext.stopService(serviceIntent), но нет. Не помогло.

Comment: а что делает unbindService ? я раньше такого не встречал. попробуйте его убрать. у меня есть приложение с фоновым сервисом и я могу его останавливать даже после того, как полностью закрыл прилагу. так что тут явно какой-то косяк в запуске / остановке сервиса.

Comment: Без unbindService уведомление не пропадает ни при каких условиях. Мы же получается создаваем уведомление и прикрепляем сервис к нему. Тем самым у нас сервис имеет наивысший приоритет и андроид его не закроет. Иначе сервис будет работать отдельно, уведомление отдельно, а андроид запрещает фоновые сервисы, особенно по работе с gps. В конечном итоге андроид или закроет сервис, или запретит ему получать геоточку.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в манифест атрибут android:stopWithTask="true". При закрытии приложения сервис будет останавливаться.

```
<service
            android:name=".services.YourService"
            android:stopWithTask="true">
            ...
</service>
```

Comment: нет, мне не нужно, чтобы сервис останавливался при закрытии приложения. мне нужно завершать сервис после повторного открытия приложения.